# blend mode for shapes in css

Tags: css, canvas, css-shapes

Let say I have some circles:

```
<circle class="first">&nbsp;</circle>
<circle class="second">&nbsp;</circle>
```

with the following css:

```
circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #000;
}
```

How can I achieve the following effect when they overlap?

[image: css circles overlap]

preferably in css, or with the canvas element.

Comment: If you're open to using SVG - you can use SVG filters to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible way is to use the [`mix-blend-mode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#mix-blend-mode) property, [which seems to be mostly not support by now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode).

Here is an example that works with Chrome and Firefox (thanks to @vals)

```css
body
{
  background-color: white;
}

.circle
{
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}

.circle:not(:first-child)
{
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Like @vals pointed out you need to set a `background-color` for the body (or parent element) in order for this to work in Firefox.

Here are two nice references on this topic:

1. https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/

Taken from this source: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/tCykv

2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: The problem with Firefox doesn't come from a white background over a white background; the body doesn't have a defined background. set body { background-color: white;} and it will work ok in Chrome and FF. +1, by the way

Comment: @vals Thank you very much for your comment. This is really interesting. I updated the answer and try to investigate a bit more :)

Answer (score 4):

## SVG

This effect can be done quite easy with a single path in <svg>

The [fill-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-rule) would be what your looking for if shapes overlapping then the effect you get is this each other shape color.

```html
<svg width="500px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 100 500">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="
        M 50, 100
        m -75, 0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0
        Z
        M 150, 100
        m -75, 0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0
        Z
        M 250, 100
        m -75, 0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0
        Z
        M 350, 100
        m -75, 0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0
        Z
        M 450, 100
        m -75, 0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0
        a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0
        Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This is definitely the way to go, if you need cross browser support. Nice.

Comment: @NicoO I like your solution but the support for it is lacking.